# Running hangfire single threaded "mode"

Tags: hangfire

Is there any way of configuring hangfire to run single threaded? I'd like the jobs to be processed sequentially, rather than concurrently.

Something like:

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.RunSingleThreaded();
            config.UseServer();
        });
```

Either this or the ability to "chain" jobs together so they happen in sequence.

Something like:

```
BackgroundJob
    .Enqueue(() => taskContainer.PublishBatch(batchId, accountingPeriodId, currentUser, filePath))
    .WithDependentJobId(23); // does not run until this job has finished...
```

Comment: Nice, my DB transaction logs were increasing too much to sustain. Answers below helped me a lot, you may read my comments below. (#huge hangfire transaction log size resolved)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should have read the docs obviously...

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html

To configure single thread use the BackgroundJobServerOptions type, and specify workerCount:

```
var server = new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
                                         {
                                             WorkerCount = 1
                                         });
```

Also, it appears [job chaining](http://hangfire.io/pro/#chaining-batches) is a feature of Hangfire Pro version.

Comment: Nice, my DB transaction logs were increasing too much to sustain. Each running worker kept a transaction log for the time it was processing, making huge transaction log size when multiple concurrent worker were in progress. I kept worker count to 5 based on my business use case and resource availability and it did the trick.

Comment: What happens here if one of the job fails? Will all upcoming jobs be held up by the retries of the one that failed?

Comment: @Lukas I seem to remember you can specify how many retries...